# Spark 2.4.0 - Different memory management options

Tags: apache-spark

Can someone help clarify various memory management options in the newest Spark 2.4.0?

From the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/configuration.html#memory-management): `spark.memory.offHeap.enabled` and `spark.memory.offHeap.size` control the size of the off-heap memory, but so does `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`. So, what exactly governs the size of off-heap memory?

Thanks.